# add random values by columns in python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I do not want this values to be updated row wise I need this column wise ..I want to update cell A2,B2,C2,D2,E2 rather than A1,A2,A3,A4

```
import openpyxl   

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()    
sheet = wb.active      
for i in range(1, 20, 2):        
    sheet.append([i])
```

Comment: You've written code to add a series of rows with a single cell; this will only ever add cells to the first column.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question and code contradict each other and the library documentation clearly covers the use case.

Answer (score 1):

Check this. You can use openpyxl to update any row and col.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
 
f = "t.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(f)
ws = wb["Sheet1"]
 
 
def modRowAndCol(row, col, val):
    cell = ws.cell(row = row, column = col)
    cell.value = val
   
for i in range(1, 5):
    for j in range(1, 5):
        modRowAndCol(i, j, f'{i, j}')
 
# save the file
wb.save('t.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 1):

Openpyxl 'append' writes to the next row after the last used row (i.e. the last row with any cell with data). 
Therefore it would be impossible to add values across row 2 only using a loop calling `sheet.append` multiple times. 

To write the values '1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15,17,19' to  cells 'A2,B2,C2,D2,E2...'  you would need to 'append' the values as a list, once only, where row 1 already had data in at least one cell.

1.The loop could be used to create the list
2. A cell in row 1 needs a value 
3. Then 'append' the list. 

Your code would work if re-written like

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.active

### Create the list of numbers to append on row 2
alist = [] 
for i in range(1, 20, 2):
    alist.append(i)

### Enter a value to a cell in Row 1
sheet['A1'].value = 'This is row 1'

### Append the list of numbers. Will be added to Row 2 since row 1 is currently the last used row.
sheet.append(alist)

wb.save('foo.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to iterate over the columns of the second row:

```py
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.active

indices = range(1, 40, 2)
cols = sheet.iter_cols(min_row=1, max_col=20)

for idx, col in enumerate(cols, start=1):
    sheet.cell(row=2, column=idx).value = idx
```